# cross compile error: previous declaration of 'group_from_gid'

Tags: linux, android-ndk

I want to compile a gdbserver for android device on Ubuntu-14.04, so I install cross compile tool as

```
apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-androideabi
```

and the configure script option for gdb is `--target=arm-linux-androideabi`,
and the option for gdbserver is `--host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi`

but when I start to compile gdbserver with `make`, here comes errors:

> arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -g -O2    -I. -I. -I./../common -I./../regformats -I./../../include -I./../gnulib/import -Ibuild-gnulib-gdbserver/import -Wall -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wpointer-arith -Wformat-nonliteral -Wno-char-subscripts -Wempty-body -Werror -DGDBSERVER -c -o linux-osdata.o -MT linux-osdata.o -MMD -MP -MF .deps/linux-osdata.Tpo ../common/linux-osdata.c
>   ../common/linux-osdata.c:1055:1: error: conflicting types for 'group_from_gid'
>   In file included from ../common/linux-osdata.c:37:0:
>   /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.7.3/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/include/grp.h:72:8: note: previous declaration of 'group_from_gid' was here
>   make: *** [linux-osdata.o] Error 1

How can I solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a workaround like this:

replace `arm-linux-androideabi` with `arm-linux-gnueabi` and make it statically link.